# ***How to select only perticular rows using Foreign Key constraint in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, database, sqlite

I want to select only 'familylist' using name 'Pankaj Lagad'. But it is giving output (Vijay Yadav, Amit Patil, null, null) I don't want "null" entry in output How to solve this problem. I am new in SQL DB.

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yL5Bx.jpg)

**********DB Design***********
CREATE TABLE android_metadata (locale TEXT);

CREATE TABLE RegistrationTable (_id integer PRIMARY KEY autoincrement,name UNIQUE,displayname,password,email,path);

CREATE TABLE FriendCircleListsTable (name CONSTRAINT [name] REFERENCES RegistrationTable,contactnumber,familylist,coworkerlist,schoolfriendlist);

Answer (score 1):

Add the following line at the very end of your script (in where clause)

```
AND FriendCircleListTable.familylist != NULL
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

instead please try `AND FriendCircleListTable.familylist IS NOT NULL`